# vaadin floating(dynamic ?) layout

Tags: user-interface, layout, vaadin, vaadin7

I use vaadin 7. I am not sure whether the "floating layout" is the proper term so let me describe what I want. 
I have more panels inside a layout. The size of those panels are fixed. If the browser window is large enough they are arranged next to each other *horizontally*. If the window does not have enough space for all of them horizontally, then the panels should be arranged *vertically*.

1, What is this kind of layout called? Floating? Dynamic?

2, How to achieve this with vaadin 7?

Neither `horizontalLayout.setSizeUndefined()` nor `horizontalLayout.setSizeFull()` work.
I am not even sure whether I need HorizontalLayout or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use the CSSLayout with width:100% and put your components inside this,
or you can look at the responsive addon.

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-responsive:vaadin

And some more about the add on

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Responsive+layouts+using+the+Responsive+extension